# In BF3, how does Reactive Armor work?

Tags: battlefield-3

Battlelog says that the panels protect you from damage but are destroyed in the process.

Specifically, what do the Reactive Armor vehicle unlocks do?

- How many panels are there?
- What constitutes damage? Up to 50 damage? 50 damage each (cumulative)? Some other algorithm
- Does using the repair tool on an enemy vehicle instantly remove the panels?

Comment: [Reactive armor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactive_armor), *in real life*!  (granted, probably not that helpful)

Comment: Sweet! I thought this was simply a game concept!

Comment: No, Battlefield pretty much has all real things (with the exception of planes landing on short roads)...what makes it so awesome!

Comment: Something I should probably ask in another question is: When does the Reactive Armour get applied? It always appears when getting into an unused vehicle. But if you are swapping seats or taking an opponents vehicle it doesn't always appear when you enter the drivers seat.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are three panels, protecting the sides and rear of the tank. No protection is given to the front of the tank. Each one can take one incoming rocket, tank shell or AT Mine before being destroyed. Once the tank's health has been repaired, the panels can be repaired by a friendly engineer. Enemy engineers can't destroy the armour using a repair tool but they can by using their RPG/SMAW or AT MINE.

To repair the Reactive armour the tank must be at 100% health. If you do know what parts of the tank does not have the armour, use the repair tool and repair the side for 3-5 seconds and should be back up.

Comment: So the panels come back AFTER the tank is at 100% AND a friendly engineer repairs the tank?

Comment: That is my understanding, yes. I have not unlocked the panels yet but everything I've read confirms that.

Comment: I actually think that it does not come back. With reactive armor equipped, the tank heading icon as the driver/gunner will show an extra line on the sides/rear of the tank where the armor is still active. After a hit to side/rear, that line is gone forever (until you spawn in another tank).

Comment: You can also see the difference in game. The sides/rear will have what looks like many small panels (boxes) if that side or rear has reactive armor still.

Comment: http://battlefield.wikia.com/wiki/Reactive_Armor :
"An engineer can repair this armor, which only takes a few seconds. However, the tank must be at 100% health in order to repair reactive armor."

I don't believe they come back on their own, but I did not say that.